# Accessing 'this' pointer from a static member function

Tags: builder

I'm trying to make a Builder (design pattern) for my class (C++).
I have a function called BookBuilder::start() which is defined as static function and it returns a BookBuilder

```
    BookBuilder BookBuilder::start()
     {
         mybook = new Book;
         return *this;
     }
```

But I'm unable to compile the code since a static member function can't access `this` pointer. How may I return a BookBuilder if I don't have access to it? The final usage of the builder will look like this:

```
Author* markTwain = new Author("Mark Twain", "twain@google.com", MALE);
Book* tomSawyer = BookBuilder::start()
            .withTitle("The Adventures of Tom Sawyer")
            .publishedBy("American Publishing Company")
            .writtenBy(*markTwain)
            .genre("Adventure")
            .isbn(68934)
            .hasPrice(100.99)
        .allocate();
```

The private part of the class BookBuilder contains only one variable which is a pointer to Book.

```
 Book* mybook;
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return a newly constructed object:

```
BookBuilder BookBuilder::start()
 {
     return new BookBuilder();
 }
```

But your function is quite strange. In builder pattern you construct the desired instance in `build()` method. Earlier you just provide elements needed to construct the final object. See simple example:

```
class BookBuilder {

    private String title; 

    private BookBuilder() {
    }

    public static BookBuilder start() {
        return new BookBuilder();
    }

    public BookBuilder withTitle(final String title) {
        this.title = title;
        return this;
    }

    public Book allocate() {
        return new Book(title);
    }
}
```

This code is written in Java. It should be easy to convert it to C++.

Comment: But I need to allocate dynamic memory for the Book (my book is a pointer). I don't have a constructor BookBuilder(Book) and can't have one (this is the requirement of the homework that I'm trying to do). I can't add any extra functions to the class (the header file is provided by the teacher)

Comment: Ok. Having seen you edited answer. In start just construct new BookBuilder then use functions like `withChapters` in my example. Do not construct the book object until `allocate()` function.

Comment: Please note that `mybook` is a pointer to Book. start() is supposed to return a BookBuilder object to use it with the functions: withTitle(), publishedBy(), etc.. While these functions directly work on the Book object, they can't be used before an Book object is created and have an allocated space for it. The function allocate() is the last function to run.

Comment: This is the point in builder pattern. Functions `withTitle()`, `publishedBy()` etc. shouldn't work on Book object. You should first store them in Builder and pass to object allocated in `allocate`.

Comment: I didn't get it. Now, I have a class with name Book. I want to make a builder. What I'm trying to do is to allocate space for a book and let the variable `mybook` point to it. I can then let the functions store data in the allocated space (names, publishers, etc..), finally I will return the address off the allocated space (which now contains the needed information). What I'm missing?

Comment: Ok having such preconditions, allocate the mybook object in ctor of Bookbuilder. But the whole point of builder is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to be returning `*mybook`.  Your first line instantiates a new `Book` and presumably that is the thing you should be returning from your function.  If that is correct you should also change the return type of your function from `BookBuilder` to `Book`.

The `this` pointer refers to the current instance, but there is no current instance for `static` functions.  `BookBuilder::start` is defined on the class itself and is run without reference to any particular instance of `BookBuilder`.

Comment: This is a homework. head files are provided by the teacher and I'm not allowed to edit them or add any additional methods to the class.